# How to make a PDF file in Laravel from parts of blade template file with user input values

Tags: php, html, laravel, pdf, input

please help me. I want to create a PDF file with domPDF in Laravel, when a button is clicked to "Create the blank". I want to take parts of the data from a blade file, to fetch the html data and make a PDF file from it. However, I also have a user  with a value that the user has to type in and it has to be put in the PDF too, how can I do that, please tell me. Please tell me the right way to do it, here is my code:

blankcreate.blade.php

```
@php
   $datahtml = '

    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
     '. $patient-> name . '

        </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" id="userinfo" />
    </div>

</div>';
@endphp
@php
echo $datahtml;
@endphp

<div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-12 text-center">
<button class="btn btn-success btn-sm container-fluid text-center" id="add-patient-blank" >
<a style="text-decoration:none; color:white;" href="localhost:8000/admin/patients/pdfblank">Create blank</a>
    </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

PatientController.php @ crblank

```
public function crblank(){
    $pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
    $pdf->loadHTML($datahtml);
    return $pdf->stream();

}
```

web.php

```
 Route::get('/admin/patients/pdfblank', 'PatientController@crblank');
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think that you should make a blade file that resembles that part of your existing blade file that you wanna copy. Then make a form that asks values that you want, get it via request and throw it on an array and feed it to dompdf via loadView to your new blade file and calling the values there. Return it by using the download function.